# Calling an external shell script inside a makefile for setting variables

Tags: shell, makefile

Take a look at the following makefile (which isn't working) ...

```
export CC      = gcc
export CFLAGS  = -W -Wall -fPIC -m32

USER = $(DB_USER)
export USER

PASS = $(DB_PASS)
export PASS

SUBDIRS = libs dbserver

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

The variables `DB_USER` and `DB_PASS` are defined in a separate external file, `conf.sh`, like this:

```
export DB_USER=<username>
export DB_PASS=<password>
```

These are then required in makefiles inside `SUBDIRS`.

If I run `. conf.sh` on the command line, and then call make, then `USER` and `PASS` are assigned the correct values, and compilation is done all fine. But I wish to call `conf.sh` inside the makefile so that these variables can be set. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(SUBDIRS):
    . conf.sh; $(MAKE) -C $@ DB_USER="$${DB_USER}" DB_PASS="$${DB_PASS}"
```

This will expose the password on the command line, but gets the job done.  Note the double-dollars; that part is evaluated by the shell, not by `make` (so the curly brackets are also necessary).  I'm not sure I recommend it, but it should work.

Come to think of it, you could probably avoid passing the parameters explicitly since the `conf.sh` script exports them.  The values for `$DB_USER` and `$DB_PASS` will be available to the subordinate `make` anyway:

```
$(SUBDIRS):
    . conf.sh; $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXPORT` defines a variable in the current shell. The variables are not visible in the caller.